# Count number of redirections using HTMLUnit

Tags: htmlunit

I am using HTMLUnit to track 302 redirection(s). When I visit a page with an instance of WebClient and one or more redirections might be involved before landing on some URL. Once I do,
`myWebClient.setRedirectEnabled(true);`, i can get the HTTP status code using `currentPage.getWebResponse().getStatusCode();` and check if it is 302. My problem is how to track the sequence of redirections to finally get total number of redirections before landing on some page. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In case you still need a solution,

[com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.WebConnectionWrapper](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/WebConnectionWrapper.html) can be used to keep track of requests and then change the response (change status code to stop further redirects)

Comment: Could you elaborate? What exactly would we use to keep track of requests. I am a bit confused. For example, if a website redirects four times, how exactly do I keep track of this, thanks!